# Client SSL Certificates in Java: PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, ssl

I have a webservice that needs a client certificate which I load at runtime using the following:

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keystore.getAbsolutePath());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "jks");


    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", cafile.getAbsolutePath());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
```

However, now my other webservice which connects via regular https (without any client certificate) is broken:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Is there a way I can load the certificates at runtime without breaking the existing https webservice?

Answer (score 0):

i tried this long back for similar problem, and was working.

```
System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol"); 
Security.addProvider (new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider()); 
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3,TLSv1"); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", ""); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", ""); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "");
Security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", ""); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", ""); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", ""); 
System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
```

Also the same can be achieved by configuring the `trustore` and `keystore` in the application server you are using.

Issue is with certificates not getting imported correctly.
I hope below links will help you out.

[Link1](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/)

[Link2](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Unable+to+Connect+to+SSL+Services+due+to+PKIX+Path+Building+Failed+sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException)

Comment: The first two lines haven't been required since about 2004. Empty KeyStore types either do not work, or else are poor practice as they obscure the fact that the default is being used. Empty passwords aren't likely to work.

Comment: @EJP Thanks Man..!! after long time i got a chance to get your feedback on my comments/questions. lot to learn from you in this field.

Comment: You haven't addressed the comments about empty passwords or KeyStore/truststore types.